# Get distinct items from rows of comma separated strings in Spark 2.0

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, data-science

I am using Spark 2.0 to analyze a data set. One column contains string data like this:

```
A,C
A,B
A
B
B,C
```

I want to get a JavaRDD with all distinct items that appears in the column, something like this:

```
A
B
C
```

How can this be done efficiently in spark? I am using Spark with Java, but Scala examples or pointers would be useful.

Edit: 
I have tried using flatMap, but my implementation is very slow.

```
JavaRDD<String> d = dataset.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(",")).iterator())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

1) explode: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(Column col)

```
static Column   explode(Column e)
```

Explode - Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

2) Then execute "distinct" on this column:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

distinct([numTasks]))   Return a new dataset that contains the distinct elements of the source dataset.

**Summary**

Explode will result with one item per row (in this specific column).

Distinct will leave only the distinct items

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "slow". Presumably you have a very large dataset (otherwise you wouldn't need Spark) so "slow" is relative. However, I would simply do

```
dataset.flatMap(s -> s.split(",")).distinct
```

Answer (score -1):

I know lengthy, but please try this if you want execution done completely at executor nodes rather than worker.

```
dataset
.flatMap(x => x.split(","))
.map(x => (x,1))
.sortByKey()
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.map(x=>x._1)
```

Add this if you get error with data format:

```
dataset.map(x=>(x._1+","+x._2+","+x._3))
```

Curious to know your findings.